# Different results from query and stored procedure in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Good day!

I am trying to do some minor null ratio analysis on some tables for our client and I wanted to create a stored procedure to make this easier to automate.

The problem I am running into is that when using the query by itself it gives the correct result but when using the stored procedure the result is different.

**Query**

```
with cte as 
(SELECT sum(case when [EstateBOA] is NULL then 1 else 0 end) as "Null Values",
        sum(case when [EstateBOA] is not NULL then 1 else 0 end) as "Not-Null Values" 
        FROM [FASTDW].[PROP].[FactBuilding]
)

SELECT '[EstateBOA]' as ColumnName,*,CAST("Null Values" AS FLOAT) /
CAST(("Null Values" + "Not-Null Values") AS FLOAT) as "Null ratio"
FROM cte
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
USE [AUDIT] 
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetNullStatsFromColumnInBuilding]    
Script Date: 2018-06-11 11:22:04 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNullStatsFromColumnInBuilding]
     @Columnname nvarchar(50)
AS
;with cte as 
(SELECT sum(case when @Columnname is NULL then 1 else 0 end) as "NullValues",
        sum(case when @Columnname is not NULL then 1 else 0 end) as "Not-Null Values" 
    FROM [FASTDW].[PROP].[FactBuilding]
)
SELECT @Columnname as ColumnName,*,  CAST("Null Values" AS FLOAT) / 
CAST(("Null Values" + "Not-Null Values") AS FLOAT) as "Null ratio"
FROM cte
```

**Query Result**

[image: Query result]

**Stored Procedure Result**
[image: Procedure Result]

Any idea why this is the case? Is it because of the "with X as" inside the stored procedure?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: In the stand-alone query you're checking whether a column value is `NULL` (i.e. the value stored in the `[EstateBOA]` column in your table). In your stored procedure you're checking whether a string value is `NULL` (i.e. the value stored in the `NVARCHAR` variable `@ColumnName`, which is passed into the proc).

Comment: Can you please try sending the value when you call the procedure without the "[]"?

Comment: You can't use a column name passed as a stored procedure parameter in the SQL statement directly. You'll need to resort to [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Comment: @DanGuzman
Ah right. That is a shame, chalk it up to my inexperience writing T-SQL procedures. Thank you for clarifying that.

Guess I will read up on some dynamic SQL then, much obliged.